# How to figure out ratings of DC supply needed to run an old elleptical trainer / cross-trainer. Currently it uses batteries

Tags: power

Folks,

I have an old elliptical which is working fine except that it has problem with the batteries as it can't hold the D size heavy batteries. There is an input for DC power supply but I was not able to figure out what are the ratings (current, voltage) required. The supplies basically goes to a console that controls all the function of the elliptical. So my question is how to figure out what are the ratings of DC power supply as I want to replace the batteries with DC supply. Currently it uses 4 1.5V D size batteries. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Elliptical](http://www.aanda.org/index.php?option=com_image&format=raw&url=/articles/aa/full/2005/46/aa3726-05/img75.gif)?

Comment: You really think just "elliptical" sufficiently defines your device!?

Comment: @OlinLathrop fwiw (not much) "elliptical" has a reasonably strong default meaning as far as the actual functionality goes. The display current requirements are not well correlated to the functionality :-). || Dave09 - if the display is LED current consumption may be higher than what Stevenh says.

Comment: Question should be closed.

Comment: So what is an elliptical?

Comment: Oh right - one of [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_trainer) I guess..

Comment: @Oli - I didn't know either, but as I often do in such case I looked it up on images.google, and then it's obvious. It *only* shows pictures of the trainer! Absolutely nothing else, like geometry. Never seen such a narrow result before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I never could understand how such a trainer needs batteries if the purpose of it is to dissipate the power you supply.)*

Anyway, 4 times 1.5 V is 6 V, and it will probably be happy with a few mA, a couple of tens at most. So a **6 V/500 mA wall wart** should do (in case it's one of Russell's LED displays, though I've never seen those, always LCD, especially for battery power). Higher than 500 mA is also OK (you'll probably won't find a lower current device.) Make sure it's one with a regulated output, otherwise the output voltage may deviate much from the nominal 6 V, and I don't know if it will stand a higher voltage.

**edit**
You'll have to pay attention on polarity, as this isn't standardized.

[image]

Wall wart type adapters may have the + on the center pin and - on the sleeve, or the other way around. The only way to know is to insert the 4 D-type cells, and measure the voltage on the connector. (I think it's a safe assumption that the adapter input goes straight to the battery connection.) Universal wall wart adapters are often supplied with a set of different connector types, which you can use for both polarities by rotating them 180°.

Answer (score 0):

A 6v regulated power pack / wall wart / plug pack / will meet your need.

If the design is all LCD then under 100 mA rating should be good.
 If it uses an LED display (as some still do) then a 500 mA rated supply or possibly even more may be required.

A power supply current rating rating higher than is required is entirely acceptable.

Typical "Eliptical" shown below.

"Real ellipticals" don't need batteries :-). Or, rather, they have rechargeable ones to handle startupo and pauses. The rest of the time they make their own power. but, many do not work this way.

I may or may not have designed the power electronics in the one shown here.
 It's the right brand, but I can't tell as they use a range of technologies and the original client is now dead and the royalty stream went all funny on me long before that, so what uses what will forever be a mystery.

Many of these and possibly this one use a bespoke alternator as an electronically variable load. Output is from 12V at a whisper of motion to up to 200V at full cry.

**I designed some of this, maybe ...**

[image]

Comment: You designed that ... and your client is now dead. Pure coincidence I hope ;)

Comment: @MikeJ-UK - Cancer :-(. I'm not that malignant, I'm pleased to say. Taiwanese made. NZ client with factory in Taichung in Taiwan.